# How to create composite index in liquibase

Tags: xml, postgresql, liquibase

How do I create a composite index using liquibase?

This is what I have so far:

```
    <createIndex indexName="idx_value"
                 tableName="test">
        <column name="value"/>
    </createIndex>
```

I have the following in mind, but I just need to confirm.

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_value"
             tableName="test">
    <column name="value0"/>
    <column name="value1"/>
</createIndex>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd be amazed if:

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_value"
             tableName="test">
    <column name="value" type="varchar(255)"/>
    <column name="othercolumn" type="varchar(255)"/>
</createIndex>
```

didn't work...

Comment: How can I explicitly state the precedence of the items on the index? Is the order in the list sufficient?

Comment: Hm, good question. Order would generally be sufficient (xml is ordered) but it's worth checking.

Comment: Yes, the order of the index is the order of the column tags in the XML

Comment: Also, when creating the index you probably don't need to define the type .

Comment: @NathanVoxland, is that probably don't or definitely don't need to define the type?  Curious if there are times it is necessary and why.  Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the target database. Some database's SQL require the type and some do not.

Answer (score 2):

For me that solution didn't work. It created separate indexes on the fields.

Instead of that, I'm using this approach, comma separating the columns:

```
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="test" columnNames="value0,value1"/>
```

Tested on MySQL 5.7 with liquibase 3.5.5